# How to "search" through the response of an XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I have a question regarding the followng code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    return xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","index.html",true);
xmlhttp.send();


}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to search through the xmlhttp.responseText (in other words call the function **loadXMLDoc()**) for key words, like for example "testfile" and if it exists multiple example "testfile_1" and "testfile_2"....."testfile_n" then **"doSomething"**

like this

```
 <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    return xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }



}
function searchADocument(wordToSearchFor){
xmlhttp.open("GET","index.html",true);
xmlhttp.send();
int numberOfTimesWordOccurs=0;
var thePageToSearchThrough [] = loadXMLDoc();
for (i=0; i<thePageToSearchThrough.length; i++){
if(thePageToSearchThrough[i]==wordToSearchFor)
 numberOfTimesWordOccurs++;
}
If  (numberOfTimesWordOccurs > 1) 
document.write("<a href="http://selnc05.go.se:8080/component_test/build/testfile_1">    testfile_1</a>"<a href="http://selnc05.go.se:8080/component_test/build/testfile_2">    testfile_2</a><a href="http://selnc05.go.se:8080/component_test/build/testfile_n">    testfile_n</a>

)

Else

window.location="http://selnc05.go.se:8080/component_test/build/testfile.html";

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="searchADocument("testfile")">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't know where to start since I don't know what type xmlhttp.responseText is, can I store it in an array and scan it using for loop etc?
Thanks in advance. =)

EDIT
What am Im doing wrong here

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

    return xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","index.html",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function searchADocument(){ //wordToSearchFor
var txt=loadXMLDoc();
if(txt.test('hello'))alert('responseText contains "hello"');
else{
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML ="helloaj";
}

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="searchADocument()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

get the following error message on  **if(txt.test('hello'))** Jscript error:'undefined' is null or not an object

---

**EDIT 3
Im guessing im just dumb as hell, but I still can't get this to work, why can't I store the xmlhttp.responseText into a variable?**

Like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp;
function loadXMLDoc(url,cfunc)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction()
{
loadXMLDoc("ajax_info.txt",function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
     var txt=xlmhttp.responseText;//This aint working, why, how can I store xlmhttp.responseText into a variable, that I can peform a search on?
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=txt;//This aint working, why?????
    }
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I can add that the above actually works if I replace the following

```
 var txt=xlmhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=txt;
```

with this

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xlmhttp.responseText;
```

I haven't got the call back function to work as mentiond below, all I get is that xmlhttp is undefined, so I ask on this that works(at least half the way I want it to).

Again sorry for not understanding, but there must be something obvious that I don't get about this, that this simply isn't possible to store this in a variable or something.

Comment: 1. `if` and `else` are statements that should be written in lowercase (JavaScript keywords are case-sensitive) 2. Your braces don't match 3. You didn't escape your double quotes inside a string 4. Using `document.write` is usually not a good idea 5. Why don't you know what type `xmlhttp.responseText` is? You're requesting a document from *your* server, so I hope you know what it sends

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt=loadXMLDoc();
```

`loadXMLDoc` doesn't return anything, so `txt` is `undefined` after this. Of course `undefined` doesn't have the `test` method, which is a method of `String.prototype`.

Instead assign a callback handler to your `XMLHttpRequest` and do whatever you want there.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
        if (xmlhttp.status==200) {
            // do something with xmlhttp.responseText
        } else {
            // do something appropriate with status
        }
}
```

**Update:** Though I think it's usually not preferrable to have these kind of copy-pasta examples, I can show you *where* you should put this piece of code. Instead of doing this:

```
function searchADocument() { //wordToSearchFor
    var txt = loadXMLDoc();
    if (txt.test('hello'))
        alert('responseText contains "hello"');
    else
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "helloaj";
}
```

where you test the return value of `loadXMLDoc` (which, as already stated, returns immediately, so *before* the request is completed), you should put your code inside the callback handler, that you assign by setting `onreadystatechange`:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        var txt=xmlhttp.responseText; /* manipulate the DOM here */
        if (txt.test('hello'))
            alert('responseText contains "hello"');
        else
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "helloaj";
    }
}
```

Comment: im not sure what you mean, I have now edited as you suggestet, but it still won't work, can you please check out www.tdsoft.se  and see for yourself what is wrong? It says that JScript runtime error: Object dosen't support this property or method, in other words "var txt=xmlhttp.responseText;" isn't a String?

Thanks again =)

Comment: @Anders – I explained this in my answer above, please read more about [XMLHttpRequest on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_xmlhttprequest). `xmlhttp.send` returns immediately, without waiting for a response of the request. You can only manipulate the response in the callback handler (or after is has been fired).

Comment: Can you please give me an example, cause im totally stuck (and yes im slow when coming to this types of issues).

Im talking about a full working example here, if you have the time that is =)