# how to store a xmlhttprequest into a variable

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I have a quick question that you brainy guys perhaps have the answer to.
Why does this work

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp;
function loadXMLDoc(url,cfunc)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction()
{
loadXMLDoc("ajax_info.txt",function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xlmhttp.responseText;
    }
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

but if I replace

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xlmhttp.responseText;
```

whit this

```
var txt=xlmhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=txt;
```

it don't work anymore, txt is

> undefined

. How can I store the xlmhttp.responseText into a string, or into a variable that I can perform a search on? Please give an example on how I can do it. Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Your variable is called `xmlhttp`, not `xlmhttp`, so try that please.

Comment: @poke– And that's because I misspelled that object name in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775471/how-to-search-through-the-response-of-an-xmlhttprequest/4775773#4775773). ;-)

Comment: Man Im just dumb as hell to not check that out, but now I know what to look for the next time, it works now :P

Answer (score 2):

Might be because you have misspelled variable "xmlhttp" - you have "xlmhttp" in your code.